# Using getters and setters to display the color

Tags: java, getter-setter

Here is my code: What I am looking to do is in the output I have color display for circle one but not in circle 2 and I am not sure why. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my first set of code:

```
 public class Circle
 {
 private double radius;
 private String color;

 public Circle()
 {
   radius = 1.0;
   color = "red";
}

public Circle(double newRadius)
{ 
    radius = newRadius;
}

public double getRadius()
{
    return radius;
}

public double getArea()
{ double ar = Math.PI * radius * radius;

    // round the area up to two decimals
    ar = Math.round(ar * 100.0) / 100.0;

    return ar;
} 
public Circle (String newColor){
   color = newColor;
}
public String getColor(){

   return color;
 }
}
```

Here is the second part with the main method:

```
 public class TestCircle
  {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Circle cir1 = new Circle();

   System.out.println("Details of circle 1:");
   System.out.println("Radius: " + cir1.getRadius());
   System.out.println("Area: " + cir1.getArea());
   System.out.println("Color: " + cir1.getColor());

   Circle cir2 = new Circle(5);
   System.out.println("******************************");
   System.out.println("Details of circle 2:");
   System.out.println("Radius: " + cir2.getRadius());
   System.out.println("Area: " + cir2.getArea());
   System.out.println("Color: " + cir2.getColor());

}
}
```

Here is the output:

Details of circle 1:

Radius: 1.0

Area: 3.14

Color: red

---

Details of circle 2:

Radius: 5.0

Area: 78.54

Color: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you only set the colour in one of your constructors.  So when you create an object such as `cir2`, using the second constructor, the colour doesn't get set.

To fix this, add a line to the second constructor to set the colour.  Maybe it could be like this.

```
public Circle(double newRadius)
{ 
    radius = newRadius;
    color = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second circle uses the constructor

```
public Circle(double newRadius)
{ 
    radius = newRadius;
}
```

which doesn't assign a color.

I'm not sure if you intended for your `newColor` method to be a constructor. You probably want a setter for color:

```
public void setColor(String newColor) {
    this.color = newColor
}
```

With this in place you could do someting along the lines of:

```
Circle cir2 = new Circle(5);
cir2.setColor("red")
System.out.println("Color: " + cir2.getColor());
```

Or, if you want it to work like `cir1`, add color assignment to the double constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

You circle 2 uses below constructor and it has no reference to setting a colour....where as default constructor does.

```
public Circle(double newRadius)
{ 
    radius = newRadius;
}
```

In my opinion, you may add another parameter to this constructor for taking a value for colour as per user's preference.